# How can I find the common axis of 2 cones in space that have the same base radius but different heights?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

How do I find the 3D vector describing the axis of 2 overlapping cones, like this:[image]

If I have only the following information:

- Coordinates of the common tip
- Coordinates of a point on the yellow cone's base
- Coordinates of a point on the blue cone's base
- The base radius (same for both)
- The separation between the tip and both bases, along the common axis

Given that the axis can be an arbitrary vector.

Comment: This implies that given the vertex, a point on the base and the length of the normal, there's only one unique cone that can be drawn, which doesn't sound right to me?

Comment: Sorry you are right

Comment: I tried another argument.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a unit vector along the common axis of the cones, let $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ be the vectors joining the vertex to the points on the yellow and blue cones' bases. Since we know the radii and the height of these cones, we can compute $\theta_1, \theta_2$ the angles between $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{b}$ respectively. So $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{a} = |\mathbf{a}|\cos{\theta_1} $, $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{b} = |\mathbf{b}|\cos{\theta_2}$ and $|\mathbf{v}| = 1$ - Three equations with three unknowns so we can solve for $\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: I actually tried something close to that but different, and arrived at system of nonlinear equations, but I was hoping there would be something "better". Take care that "v" is 3 unknowns though not 1. 

(Side note: I don't know who downvoted, but I don't think it's useful to downvote without a comment)

Comment: Say $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$. Using the first two equations, you can express $v_2, v_3$ as a linear function of $v_1$. Plugging in $|\mathbf{v}| = 1$ will give you a quadratic equation in $v_1$ which is easy to solve. What could be better than this?

Comment: but the angles are unknowns too.

Comment: How come? $\theta_1 = \angle AOD$ where $A$ is the point on yellow cone's base, $O$ is the vertex of cone, $AC$ is the axis with $C$ lying on the base of yellow cone (we don't know $C$ yet but $AO$, $OC$ and $AC$ are given).

Comment: You're right, I'll give it a shot. Thanks.